# Unable to complete Xcode download

Tags: xcode, mac-appstore

I am downloading the latest version of Xcode (Version 10.0) from the Mac App Store.

After having downloaded about 90%; it is hung so I am unable to complete the download and the App Store icon on the dock shows a red circle with 1 in it indicating the pending download.

When I go to the Launchpad and try to pause the same and resume; it does not work as the icon is not highlighted in the first place so I can not click on it to pause it. I see the bar showing about 90% download.

[image: App Store Status]
[image: Launchpad Icon]

Is there a way to pause and resume it? I am using macOS High Sierra 10.13.6 on a MacBook Pro (13", Mid 2012).

Comment: The install completed and I can start the app normally to use. However the Xcode app icon in the launchpad is still greyed out.